# How to work with HTML table and make multiple rows with only one <tr>?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to change an html `<table>` in order to make it responsive,
But I want to work only with `css`

```css
table{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
}

.a{
   width:100% !important;
  background-color:Red; 
 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td class="a">AAA</td>
         <td class="b">BBB</td>
         <td class="c">CCC</td>
     </tr>   
      
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want :

Without changing HTML, I want to have the AAA for the 100% width of the screen, and "BBB" + "CCC" below (under the AAA line with BBB : 50% width, and the "CCC" too in width)

I'm trying with no success, any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you against changing the default `display: table;` of the `table` ?

If no, you can do like this

```
.a{
  width:100%;
  background-color:Red;
}
.b, .c { width: 49%; display: inline-block }


table, tbody, tr, td { display: block; }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gc676y4q/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` but that sort of negates the point of using a table in the first place.

If this isn't tabular data (and the layout suggests it's not) then you really should be looking for an alternative HTML structure.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  width: 110px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
td.a {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">AAA</td>
      <td class="b">BBB</td>
      <td class="c">CCC</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```